# What is the best racket in the world?

Tags: badminton, racket

I have heard that the best rackets that are lighter, powerful and fast racket models are Duora 7 and Glanz in Yonex brand.
Are these rackets best ones?
Is there any better ones?

Answer (score 1):

Badminton rackets vary among a number of properties, none of which are a simplistic *worse vs better*:

- Their **balance**, some rackets being more head-heavy, others being more head-light. As a rule of thumb, head-heavy rackets are better in the offense (when you want to generate lots of power), head-light rackets are better in defense and quick net play.
- Their **weight**. Similar to the balance, a lighter racket is better for defense, a heavier racket tends to allow you to play more powerful shots. In contrast to balance, the variety in weight is larger; really heavy(120g+) training rackets allow you to feel incorrect technique and build up strength.
- Their **form**. The laws of Badminton limit the size of the racket, but there are differences in form. Different forms are not so much about a larger area of the racket in general, but the size of the area where contact is optimal. Some rackets (namely, the YONEX Duora line) also have two different sides with different properties.
- Their **stiffness**: All good badminton rackets [bend on power hits](http://g1.img-dpreview.com/C9550BE80A6344E1A91BE9F12C705A1C.jpg), but some are more flexible than others. For players that are able to generate speed very quickly (i.e. virtually all professionals), a stiffer racket means more power is transferred onto the shuttle. For players who take longer to accelerate, a flexible racket is better, because it will store the power for a longer time.
- Their **grip size**: Depending on your finger length, different grip sizes tend to be optimal. Naturally, the grip size is intertwined with balance and weight.

Rackets feeling will also vary by the outfit:

- The **string type**: Narrow strings tend to give more feeling and power, but break faster. Also, the composition and production of the string impacts the final control.
- The **string tension**: Higher string tensions limit the area where you can hit effectively, and transfer more power on very short hitting actions. On the other hand, a lower tension increases the sweet spot, and introduces a small trampoline effect. Therefore, [string tension depends on skill as well as personal preference](http://badminton-coach.co.uk/272/why-egos-and-incorrect-information-about-string-tensions-in-badminton-could-be-doing-more-harm-than-good/). Note that not all rackets work are strong enough for higher tensions.
- The **grip** mainly changes the size of the handle, and may also have a very slight effect on balance.
- The **overgrip** (or grip if you don't use an overgrip) material determines how good you can hold your racket. Towel grips tend to be problematic for players with very sweaty hands, and need to be powdered regularly. Plastic grips come with different surfaces.

There are some aspects where some rackets *are* better than others, namely average **durability** and **price**.

Some properties do not effect play, but are considered anyways: **style/coloring** and **marketing**.

In summary, **there is no best racket**. The best racket for a given player depends a lot on the player's technique, playing style, preferences and personal feeling. Most players will play fine with a any good racket, especially if the new racket's properties are similar to their usual racket.